# TPU pod v2-32 for jupyter notebook

Tags: python, keras, tpu

I used below code to train my model in v3-8 TPU which is single device TPU, it works fine, however, the same code does not work on TPU pod v2-32. As I know v2-32 are clusters of TPU devices that are connected to each other over dedicated high-speed networks, so how to tweak the code to make it work on v2-32?

```
tpu = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(tpu="tpu-name", zone="us-central1-a", project="myproject")
tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(tpu)
tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(tpu)
strategy = tf.distribute.TPUStrategy(tpu)

....... code to load data and define model ......

with strategy.scope(): 
    myModel = createModel()
    ....
    ....
```

it works perfectly on v3-8 single TPU, but on TPU pod v2-32, it gives error: invalidargument ... unable to find the relevant tensor remote_handle .....

how to configure strategy for v2-32 as clusters of TPU in jupyter notebook?

Comment: Could you make sure that your TPU Pod has the same Tensorflow version as the VM, and they both are in the same project/zone (and no need to pass those in TPUClusterResolver). There should be no difference in training on a single TPU vs TPU pod.

Comment: @Gagik, I did checked TPU Pod and VM both are in the same zone, project, and same version of Tensorflow.

Comment: what TF versions do you use? Could you try a simple MNIST example on your TPU pod and see if that work? for example the one from here: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tpu just update TPUClusterResolver(tpu=your_tpu_name)

Comment: @Gagik, I am using tensorflow 2.4 for both VM and TPU. It is not working. It is too expensive to turn on v2-32 to keep testing, I have to just use v3-8. Thank you.

Comment: @Gagik, I am running code in Jupyter notebook, I might try to execute python script by creating VM & v2-32 see if it is working. Thanks, Ling

Comment: Did you solved? please post the solution

Comment: @LucianoDourado No, I did not resolve the issue.

Comment: @Ling, do you remember what "tpu_name" was exactly? Was it an gRPC address, or the name of the TPU instance?

Answer (score 0):

To connect to a TPU Pod, you need to pass **the name of the TPU Pod instance** as `tpu` argument of `TPUClusterResolver`. I stumbled upon similar error in December 2021, when I used the following code (which uses `TPUClusterResolver.connect()`):

```py
resolver = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver.connect(
    tpu="grpc://[ip-address-of-the-node]:8470", 
    zone="europe-west4-a", 
    project="my-awesome-project")
```

and found out that passing the node's gRPC address (`grpc://[ip-address-of-the-node]:8470`) results in `InvalidArgumentError`.

I could not find definitive information related to this problem, but here's what I found:

1. A previous revision of Google Cloud documentation warned users about this behaviour (although the error message is different):

> For single device training, you can specify either the TPU name or an IP address, for example: `grpc://1.2.3.4:8470`.
>
> For TPU Pods you must use the TPU name so that TensorFlow can discover the IP addresses of all the hosts available for training distribution.
>
> Specifying the IP address for a TPU Pod generates the following error:
> `ValueError: TPUConfig.num_shards is not set correctly ....`
>
> *From Google Cloud Documentation (rev. 2020-03-01), archived at: https://web.archive.org/web/20200301111416/https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/training-on-tpu-pods/ (last access: 2022-01-22)*

2. A similar issue was reported on GitHub (https://github.com/google-research/bert/issues/885#issuecomment-546218170)

Note that this only happened (on me) on TPU Pods; with TPU v2-8 or v3-8, I could access the node with either a gRPC address or a node name.